# How to set max width of tooltip in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

How to set max width of tooltip in primefaces?

```
<p:tooltip for="#{c.id}_checkBox" value="#{c.tooltipText}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Which one? `p:tooltip` or `pe:tooltip`?

Comment: Using CSS? `p:tooltip` has `style` and `styleClass` attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
                            <style type="text/css">
                            .ui-tooltip {
                                    max-width: 400px;
                                    white-space:pre-wrap;
                                }
                        </style>
```